# Mapping Values in multiple Python dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have 2 "empty" dicts:

```
keys_in = ["in1","in2"]
dict2 ={key: None for key in keys_in}
keys_out = ["out1","out2"]
dict3 ={key: None for key in keys_out}
```

And I want to "map" one of the values from a dict to the other:

```
dict3["out1"] = dict2["in1"]
```

So that if the value of `dict2["in1"]` is set, I get the same value in `dict3["out1"]`

Is this possible? tried this and the value is not changed:

```
keys_in = ["in1","in2"]
dict2 ={key: None for key in keys_in}
keys_out = ["out1","out2"]
dict3 ={key: None for key in keys_out}

dict3["out1"] = dict2["in1"]
dict2["in1"]  = 4

print(dict3["out1"]) #keeps being None
print(dict2["in1"]) # this of course  is 4
```

I got this idea thinking on C++ pointers, I'm not sure if I'm in the right direction:s

Comment: this is not how python works, but you can try using `list`s instead of `None`. this will make somewhat similar behavior to C++ pointers. however, this will affect runtime and can be quite cumbersome to maintain

Comment: A possible way is to assign both entries the same value and create another dict as the "address to value" dict.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not how assignment works in Python. Please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) or read [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). tl;dr: **names are reassigned independently**.

Without any further context, you *could* create a mutable object and use it in the values of both dicts. I have never seen a use case for this and we're probably dealing with an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, but an example might be educational.

```
class MutableValue:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> dict1 = {'in1': MutableValue(4)}
>>> dict2 = {'out1': dict1['in1']}
>>> dict1
{'in1': 4}
>>> dict2
{'out1': 4}
>>> dict1['in1'].value = 5
>>> dict1
{'in1': 5}
>>> dict2
{'out1': 5}
```

---

Just for fun, we can  take this further:

```
from collections import UserDict

class MutableValueDict(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key in self:
            self[key].value = item
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, MutableValue(item))
```

Demo:

```
>>> dict1 = MutableValueDict({'in1': 4})
>>> dict2 = MutableValueDict({'out1': dict1['in1']})
>>> dict1
{'in1': 4}
>>> dict2
{'out1': 4}
>>> dict1['in1'] = 5 # no need to access .value
>>> dict1
{'in1': 5}
>>> dict2
{'out1': 5}
```

Comment: Just for the record, what makes it mutable is  the definition of `def __repr__(self):` ?

Comment: @Ivan no, `__repr__` is only defined such that in the example the dict does not look like this: `{'in1': <__main__.MutableValue object at 0x000001C8273FE850>}`. What makes a `MutableValue` mutable is simply the fact that you can freely reassign the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way to reach a *similar* result is to set a callable function to each value of the dependent dictionary, `dict3`, which has access to the value stored in the original dictionary, `dict2`. As drawbrack to access to a value in `dict3` an empty call should de done, i.e. `dict3['out1']()`.

Natural assumption: both dictionary have the same amount of items (and the right order).

```
# default initialisation
keys_in = ["in1","in2"]
dict2 = dict.fromkeys(keys_in, None)

# create a dictionary with callable values
keys_out = ["out1","out2"]
dict3 = {k3: lambda: dict2[k2] for k2, k3 in zip(keys_in, keys_out)}

# check content
print(dict3['out1']())

# add content to first dict
dict2['in1'] = 'dict2 -> in1'
dict2['in2'] = 'dict2 -> in2'

# check the updates
print(dict3['out1']())
#'dict2 -> in1'
print(dict3['out2']())
#'dict2 -> in2'
```

Here an functional programming way to access to the values of the `dict3` just to stress that all of its values are callables:

```
from operator import methodcaller

vs = list(map(methodcaller('__call__'), dict3.values()))
print(vs)
```